# Styling ToC dot leader using emdash and other formatting requirements

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

I'm using `memoir` class and want to create ToC that:

1. Using em dash (instead of default dot leaders) between TOC item and page number.
2. This style should apply to both part and chapter name.
3. Only the part name using bold font.
4. Add vertical space between each part group.

like this one:

[image: TOC style that I want to create]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Part 1
\part{Title of part 1 goes here}
\chapter[Title of chapter 1]{Title of chapter 1} \chaptermark{Title of chapter 1} % Chapter 1
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\chapter[Just another chapter]{Just another chapter} \chaptermark{Just another chapter} % Chapter 2
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\chapter[Yes, keep up writing]{Yes, keep up writing} \chaptermark{Yes, keep up writing} % Chapter 3
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage

% Part 2
\part{Just another part}
\chapter[Another part, another chapter]{Another part, another chapter} \chaptermark{Another part, another chapter} % Chapter 4
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\chapter[Another chapter goes here]{Another chapter goes here} \chaptermark{Another chapter goes here} % Chapter 5
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage

% ...and so on...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Hupfer. It's great to be here. I'm a novice to LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is taken directly from the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [basic user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf); specifically section **9.2.2 Typesetting the entries** on the class ToC methods:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\chapterstyle{dash}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Redefinitions of \part-entry in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftpartname}{Part~}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{---}
\renewcommand{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{%
  \cftpartformatpnumhook{#1}%
  {\cftpartpagefont #1}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\hfill\null}

% Redefinition of \chapter-entry in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{---}
\let\oldcftchapterfont\cftchapterfont
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\oldcftchapterfont\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{%
  \cftchapterformatpnumhook{#1}%
  {\cftchapterpagefont #1}}
\let\oldcftchapterpagefont\cftchapterpagefont
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\oldcftchapterpagefont\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\hfill\null}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Part 1
\part{Title of part 1 goes here}
\chapter{Title of chapter 1}% Chapter 1
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Just another chapter}% Chapter 2
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Yes, keep up writing}% Chapter 3
\lipsum[1-2]

% Part 2
\part{Just another part}
\chapter{Another part, another chapter}% Chapter 4
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Another chapter goes here}% Chapter 5
\lipsum[1-2]

% ...and so on...

\end{document}
```

Specific to your requirements (where `X` denotes either `part` or `chapter`):

1. Set `\cftpartleader` to `---`;
2. Set `\cftchapterleader` to `---`;
3. Remove the `\bfseries` from `\cftchapterfont` by saving it (via `\let`) as `\oldcftchapterfont` and appending `\mdseries` to it. This also holds for the page number font `\cftchapterpagefont`.
4. The default is to insert a vertical skip before every `\part` in the ToC.

Some additional steps were added:

5. Precede each entry with its name (`Part` or `Chapter`);
6. Change the component after the sectional unit number (`\cftXaftersnum`) to be a colon `:`;
7. Update each entry to end with `\hfill\null`, thereby avoiding underfull `\hbox`es, since every entry in the ToC is set in a box of fixed width.

Comment: You might be interested in adding `\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}` to remove the space before every `\chapter` setting.

Comment: May I ask another questions, please?

Comment: (1) How to adjust font size of the Part Name;

Comment: (2) How to change font attribute of the Part name to normal (instead of bold);

Comment: (3) How to start the Part or Chapter number to greater number, let's say Part number 30, and Chapter number 100. PS: I have 583 chapters in 61 parts. I want to see how it looks like before jumping into real code. Thank you.

Comment: Just found the answer for question #3 above. I use `\setcounter{part}{61}` and `\setcounter{chapter}{583}`

Comment: @Ekosan: (1) Adjust `\cftpartfont` (default is `\large\bfseries`); for example `\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\Large\bfseries`}` (2) Use the same as in (1), but remove `\bfseries`.

Comment: @Warner: Thank you so much. You really saved my day. I just simulated chapter 583 part 61 using `\setcounter{chapter}{583}` and `\setcounter{part}{61}`. Now the chapter numbers seem too close to the chapter names. Also, I want to have a bit more space between part numbers and part names. What kind of command should I use to adjust these settings? Thank you. PS: I want to attach a screenshot here, but don't know how. Sorry...

Comment: I forgot to mention: I just change the Part numbering to arabic using `\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}` and modify previous code, so it says `Part 1, Part 2, etc`. So, just forget about partname numbering. What still bothering is the distance between Chapter numbers and chapter names. They're just too close. Thank you.

Comment: @Ekosan: For `\part`s that are set with `\Roman` numerals, their widths can vary greatly across 61 possible numbers. So, use `\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:\space} \renewcommand{\partnumberlinebox}[2]{#2}`. Alternatively you can try adjusting `\cftpartnumwidth` to suit your needs. For example, try `\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{3em}` (where you adjust `3em`). Then, for `\chapter`s, it seems sufficient to use `\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}`.