# ToC content spacing and related formatting

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, memoir

I'm working in `memoir` class and creating ToC with both short and (sometimes very) long chapter title. I need to:

1. Adjust horizontal spacing between part\chapter number and the title so they won't be overlapped, no matter how long the digits\numbers are. The left part of longer-number title doesn't have to be aligned with the shorter one. I prefer the spacing would be automatic/adjustable (depends on the part or chapter digit/number). Thanks. 
   [image: overlapping chapter number and title]  [image]
2. Sometimes there's an unwanted vertical spacing between two chapter title in random.  [image: unwanted vertical spacing]

What is the proper way to fix them? I've tried to search for same problems here, but still no luck. Accident/unwanted vertical spacing is still bothering. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm, paperheight=210mm, margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}

% simulate larger part and chapter number
\setcounter{part}{50}
\setcounter{chapter}{1200}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is My First Part}
\chapter{This is first chapter}
\chapter{This is very very long chapter title}
\chapter{Next chapter goes here}

\part{This is My Second Chapter}
\chapter{Very long chapter title also goes here}
\chapter{Another chapter goes here}
\chapter{Another chapter goes here}
\chapter{Another chapter goes here}

% ...and so on...

\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

In addition to my Pastebin, here's the replicated `main.tex`.
Hope this helps. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm, paperheight=210mm, margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% quote
\newcommand*\openquote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{``}}}
\newcommand*\closequote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{''}}}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Azure}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@right
\def\shadequote{\@righttrue\shadequote@i}
\def\shadequote@i{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
\def\endshadequote{%
  \if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}
\@namedef{shadequote*}{\@rightfalse\shadequote@i}
\@namedef{endshadequote*}{\endshadequote}
\makeatother
% END quote setting

\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\chapterstyle{dash}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}

% ToC Setting
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201358/styling-toc-dot-leader-using-emdash-and-other-formatting-requirements
% Redefinitions of \part-entry in ToC
% \renewcommand{\cftpartname}{Part~}
\renewcommand{\cftpartname}{Part~}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{---}
\renewcommand{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{%
  \cftpartformatpnumhook{#1}%
  {\cftpartpagefont #1}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\hfill\null}

% Redefinition of \chapter-entry in ToC
% \renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter~}
% \renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{---}
\let\oldcftchapterfont\cftchapterfont
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\oldcftchapterfont\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{%
  \cftchapterformatpnumhook{#1}%
  {\cftchapterpagefont #1}}
\let\oldcftchapterpagefont\cftchapterpagefont
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\oldcftchapterpagefont\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\hfill\null}

% Distance between part and chapter
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1em} % part
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{3pt} % chapter

% Arabic-style page numbering
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129592/add-parts-to-the-table-of-contents
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}

% change font size of ToC item & number
% \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% GOOD (by Werner)
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/toc-content-spacing-and-related-formatting?noredirect=1#comment470627_201940
\renewcommand{\partnumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }
\renewcommand{\chapternumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }

% Past:
%\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2em}
%\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2em}

% --- END ToC settings

% RUNNING HEADER
% The following code have been found in Peter Wilsons Memoir manual in chapter 7 (page127)
\makepagestyle{My_pagestyle} % Create a new pagestyle

% Following code to edit the pagestyle
\makepsmarks{My_pagestyle}{\nouppercaseheads

% This is where we specify what \leftmark and \rightmark contains
%\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{\space}
%\createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{\space}
% Change "shownumber" to "nonumber" if you don't want the chapter/section number displayed at the header.
\createmark{title}{left}{nonumber}{}{\space}
\createmark{chapter}{right}{nonumber}{}{\space}
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}}
% Might want to keep those, see the manual for further information.

% The following is where you tweek your header
% http://hstuart.dk/2007/06/12/styling-the-page-footer-and-header/
% For verso pages
\makeevenhead{My_pagestyle}{\normalfont\thepage\hskip.5cm\vrule\hskip.5cm\footnotesize\Booktitle}{}{}
% For recto pages
\makeoddhead{My_pagestyle}{}{}{\footnotesize\rightmark\hskip.5cm\vrule\hskip.5cm\normalfont\thepage}

% Activate your new pagestyle
\pagestyle{My_pagestyle}

% --- END

% The 'Part' page
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49512/part-style-in-memoir-class/49534#49534
\renewcommand\partname{Part}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\large} % part name
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\normalfont\large} % part number
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\LARGE} % part title
\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\par\parbox{0.5in}{\hrulefill}\par} 

\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}

% Set book title and the writer's name
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195863/include-document-title-in-memoir-class-header
% http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=15857
\def\Booktitle{My book title goes here}
\title{\Booktitle}
\author{The writer's name}
\date{}

% Let's do it
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

% ENDORSEMENT
\pagestyle{empty}
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/endorsement}
\cleardoublepage % Start a new odd page (manually)

% BOOK TITLE
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/booktitle-01}
\cleardoublepage % Start a new odd page (manually)
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/booktitle-02}

% BOOK INFO, ISBN, ETC
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/kdt}

% DEDICATION
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/dedication}

\pagestyle{My_pagestyle}

% FOREWORDS
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/intro}
\cleardoublepage % Start a new odd page (manually)

% TOC
\tableofcontents

% SET PAGE NUMBERING (1, 2, 3.. for main content)
\mainmatter

% PROLOG
\include{./include/00-prelims-pages/prolog}


% PART 1
\part{This is Part}
\include{./include/part-01/01}
\include{./include/part-01/02}
\include{./include/part-01/03}
\include{./include/part-01/04}
\include{./include/part-01/05}
\include{./include/part-01/06}

% PART 2
\part{Part}
\include{./include/part-02/01}
\include{./include/part-02/02}
\include{./include/part-02/03}
\include{./include/part-02/04}
\include{./include/part-02/05}
\include{./include/part-02/06}
\include{./include/part-02/07}
\include{./include/part-02/08}
\include{./include/part-02/09}
\include{./include/part-02/10}
\include{./include/part-02/11}

% PART 3
\part{Part}
\include{./include/part-03/01}
\include{./include/part-03/02}
\include{./include/part-03/03}
\include{./include/part-03/04}

% ...and so on...

% ABOUT THE WRITER
\cleardoublepage % Start a new odd page (manually)
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{./include/about-writer}

% ...and so on...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package for adjust your TOC for avoid those character collisions.

Comment: I am not an expert about `memoir`, but I wonder about this feature. Do you really need 50 parts, 1500 etc. chapters?

Comment: @Aradnix tocloft is already build into memoir, so see the chapter about toc formatting in the memoir manual

Comment: Your minimal example only replicates problem (1), not (2). To solve (1), add `\renewcommand{\partnumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }
\renewcommand{\chapternumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }` to your preamble. It allows for a flexible spacing around the number for both `\part`s and `\chapter`s.

Comment: @daleif I've never used memoir, I have reviewed its documentation very briefly, but it is a useful data, thanks.

Comment: @Hupfer: Hi, I just reached home. Yes, I know it might sound silly or crazy. But I do have that book right now, consist of 601 chapters in 61 part for now. Perhaps still counting :) . Sorry I can't post the real screenshot here right now. I'm pretty new to LaTeX, and this is my first LaTeX project. PS: I'm using Texmaker under Linux. Why does it lags often when compiling to PDF?

Comment: @Hupfer: off course not exactly that much. Only 601 chapters in 61 parts for now. Perhaps still counting. But I hope not :D

Comment: @Aradnix: I use `\usepackage{titletoc}`. I read somewhere here (I forget the link, sorry). Thanks.

Comment: @Hupfer: Neither do I. I'm just a novice, mate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your minimal example only replicates problem (1), not (2). To solve (1), add

```
\renewcommand{\partnumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }
\renewcommand{\chapternumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }
```

to your preamble. It allows for a flexible spacing around the number for both `\part`s and `\chapter`s, effectively discarding the requirement to place the part/chapter number inside a box of (fixed) width given by `#1`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand{\partnumberlinebox}[2]{Part~#2 }
\renewcommand{\chapternumberlinebox}[2]{#2 }

% simulate larger part and chapter number
\setcounter{part}{50}
\setcounter{chapter}{1200}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is My First Part}
\chapter{This is first chapter}
\chapter{This is very very long chapter title}
\chapter{Next chapter goes here}

\part{This is My Second Chapter}
\chapter{Very long chapter title also goes here}
\chapter{Another chapter goes here}
\chapter{Another chapter goes here}
\chapter{Another chapter goes here}

% ...and so on...

\end{document}
```

In the example above I've prepended each `\part`-like entry with `Part~` as well.

Comment: Thank you, Werner. I've tried it but still can't replicate the problem. I'm trying to re-post the code. Thank you. UPDATE: The unwanted vertical spacing sometimes also occurred between part name and its chapters beneath.

Comment: @Ekosan: You can post you `.aux` and/or `.toc` file somewhere (like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)) for the community to inspect. Not sure what it might deliver, but it could help...

Comment: Okay, will try soon. UPDATE: [here's the `.aux` file (replicated)](http://pastebin.com/zg3yZ1jA). I'm sorry, I can't show the real wording. I replace the real ones with plain wording to match the real pattern (words count, words number, mark, etc) as close as possible. Does it really matter? Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: @Ekosan: Nothing in the `.aux` indicate that spaces are added to to the ToC. If you can identify the chapters around which it happens, examine their individual `.aux` files.

Comment: I've deleted all `.aux` files, but still no luck. Still have 3 unwanted spacing issues (1 between part and chapter, the rest are between chapters). Thanks.

Comment: Each of my chapter files start with the `\chapter` and `\chaptermak`. If it's too long, a `\ldots` trims the end, like so: `\chapter[This is a very long chapter title you might never seen before]{This is a very long chapter title you might never seen before} \chaptermark{This is a very long chapter title you mi\ldots}`. Does it possibly cause the mysterious vertical spacing in ToC? Thank you.

Comment: @Ekosan: That should not make any difference. I don't know how to solve your issue since I can't replicate it.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you very much for your time and effort. Please disregard the issue for now. I'll be continuing working on the script. // Just in case you need to inspect, I just uploaded two chapter `.aux` files in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) which has an unwanted space in ToC. The space lies between [this one](http://pastebin.com/HPpW429U) and [this one](http://pastebin.com/B8M3XLLt).

Answer (score 1):

[Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202077/126270) seemed very authoritative, but when I tried it, I got the error

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: \partnumberlinebox undefined.
> ```

Consulting the [memoir manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) suggested to me that the correct incantation was actually

```
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{#1\hspace{1em}}
```

and indeed that worked great for me! Here's my test case:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% \renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}}  % attempt 1, failed
% \renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{#1\hspace{1em}}     % attempt 2, worked

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First}
\part{Second}
\part{Third}
\part{Fourth}
\end{document}
```

It appears that `\partnumberline` is supported at least as far back as `memoir.cls` version `2011/03/06 v3.6j` (which is what I have), and `\partnumberlinebox` is a newer addition. I'm not sure why one would prefer one over the other.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, both solutions work. Maybe you have an outdated version of `memoir.cls`. The current version is something like `2016/05/16 v3.7f `.

Comment: Correct, my system has `2011/03/06 v3.6j`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.